# Convert LaTeX file to word including a lot of tikzpictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, conversion, msword

I need to convert a latex file to MS word which contains a lot of tikz-pictures. To make the conversion more easy, the converter schould automatically replace the tikzpicture blocks with an includegraphics command to to corresponding pdf of the picture and convert before conversion.

Is there any script or converter which can do this?

Comment: I guess that `tikz` externalization should work in this case. It works with `tex4ht`, which can convert to `odt` format, which can be in turn converted to Word

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tex4ht` to convert LaTeX to OpenDocument format, which can be then easily converted to Word using LibreOffice. It supports TikZ externalization, so you save your drawings in suitable format first and use them in the conversion process afterwards. It seems that the most suitable image format to use is `png`. A vector format like `svg` or `pdf` would be better, but they are unsupported in the `odt` format, so no luck here, we must stick with bitmaps.

You haven't provided a `mwe`, so here is mine:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, ngerman]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usetikzlibrary{external}    
\tikzset{
 external/system call/.add={}                                                
 {;  rungs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pngalpha -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -r110 -sOutputFile=\image.png \image.pdf }
}
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}{
}{
    \tikzexternalize
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=0.8\textwidth,
height=0.3\textheight,
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=1,
xlabel={Dimensionless number $\zeta$ (-)},
xlabel style={fill=white,fill opacity=0.9},
ymin=0,
ymax=2000,
ylabel={Resulting pressure $\Sigma p$ (bar)},
ylabel style={fill=white,fill opacity=0.9},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
legend style={at={(0.71,0.96)},anchor=north west,draw=black,fill=white,legend cell align=left}
]
%% Formula 1
\addplot[blue, domain=0:1, samples=101]
{1998*(1 - x^2)};
\addlegendentry{Formula 1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Resulting pressure $\Sigma p$ as a function of $\zeta$ \label{fig:spz}}
\end{figure}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (2,2) ellipse (3cm and 1cm);
  \node (2,2) {Hello};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You can compile the document using:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape filename.tex
```

It will create two `png` images.

The interesting bits in this TeX file are these

```
\usetikzlibrary{external}    
\tikzset{
 external/system call/.add={}                                                
 {;  rungs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pngalpha -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -r110 -sOutputFile=\image.png \image.pdf }
}
```

This is configuration for TikZ externalization. `rungs` command is version of GhostScript shipped with TeX distributions, so it should work everywhere. You may want to play with the parameters, in order to get the best result.

```
\@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}{
}{
    \tikzexternalize
}
```

This piece will ensure that the configuration from the above is used only when the document is not compiled using `tex4ht`, because we need to use special configuration in that case.

The configuration for `tex4ht` is provided in a file with `.cfg` extension, like `mycfg.cfg`:

```
\tikzset{
    tex4ht inc/.style={
        /pgf/images/include external/.code={%
            \includegraphics[]{##1.png}%
        }

    }
}
\tikzexternalize[mode=only graphics]  
\tikzset{tex4ht inc}
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

This configuration basically tells TikZ not to generate the images for figures, but to include the `png` images created in the previous step instead.

You can compile the document using `tex4ht` now. The command is following:

```
mk4ht oolatex filename.tex mycfg
```

with this result:

[image]